# Wordpress - Function to save random order of numbers in post upon publishing

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a way to save the numbers 0-9 in a random order in two lists when a post is published in Wordpress so without entering anything in the editor the post will display something like this when the post is published and these numbers will be saved for that post but the numbers will display differently for each post:

```
<ul class="list-one">
    <li class="box-1"> 7 </li>
    <li class="box-2"> 5 </li> 
    <li class="box-3"> 2 </li> 
    <li class="box-4"> 4 </li> 
    <li class="box-5"> 1 </li> 
    <li class="box-6"> 8 </li> 
    <li class="box-7"> 9 </li> 
    <li class="box-8"> 3 </li> 
    <li class="box-9"> 0 </li> 
    <li class="box-10"> 6 </li> 
</ul>
<ul class="list-two">
    <li class="box-1"> 8 </li>
    <li class="box-2"> 4 </li> 
    <li class="box-3"> 6 </li> 
    <li class="box-4"> 0 </li> 
    <li class="box-5"> 2 </li> 
    <li class="box-6"> 7 </li> 
    <li class="box-7"> 5 </li> 
    <li class="box-8"> 3 </li> 
    <li class="box-9"> 1 </li> 
    <li class="box-10"> 9 </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this need to display as post content

Answer (score 0):

In `Loop`, you can use [`get_the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) function to fetch the content of the post, after which you can add your `HTML` to it and then `echo`.

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
    ...

    // Get the post content
    $post_content = get_the_content;

    // Generate first list with random numbers
    $list_one = '<ul class="list-one">';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $list_one .= '<li class="box-'.($i + 1).'"> '.rand(0, 9).' </li>';
    }

    $list_one .= '</ul>';

    // Generate second list with random numbers
    $list_two = '<ul class="list-two">';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $list_two .= '<li class="box-'.($i + 1).'"> '.rand(0, 9).' </li>';
    }

    $list_two .= '</ul>';

    // Add the generated lists to the content

    $post_content .= $list_one.$list_two;

    // And then display it

    echo $post_content;

    ...
?>
```

**UPDATE 2**

You have to use `save_post` action. From the official docuementation:

> *save_post* is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated, which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by email.

Use it like this:

```
function doSomething($post_id) {
    // fetch the post by ID, check if it is newly created,
    // generate your lists, append to it and update it
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'doSomething' );
```

Here is a nuance, which is also highlighted in docs. For updating the post you will need to call the `wp_update_post` function, which in its turn will call the `save_post`. This will cause an infinite loop. To avoid this, you have to `remove_action` inside your function like this:

```
function doSomething($post_id) {
    // Remove your action
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'doSomething' );

    // fetch the post by ID, check if it is newly created,
    // generate your lists and append to it

    // Update the post
    wp_update_post(/* ... */);

    // Add your action again
    add_action( 'save_post', 'doSomething' );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'doSomething' );
```

For more details about `save_post`, please check [the official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).

Comment: I think you've misunderstood - I need to generate the two lists separate from the content so when I publish a post the two lists of random sequences will appear at the bottom but each must contain 0-9 and no number can appear twice in it's list.

Comment: Thank you Karlen this is close but I need it to remain the same and be saved in the post. This code changes each time the page is refreshed. Also this is giving lists like 4 5 3 3 1 1 6 4 9 8 where certain numbers are repeated, I need it so no number is repeated in the list, is this possible?

Comment: I have updated my answer again. Please check it out.

Comment: Thank you again so what exactly would I put into my functions file? Sorry for all the questions.